# Windows Photos App "Save" instead of "Save a Copy" as the default

Tags: windows-10, default-settings, windows-photo-viewer

Every time I wish to Save a photo, instead of creating a new file for the edits just made, I have to click on the arrow which gives the "Save" option instead of the "Save a copy" option.

[image]

So, How do I make the "Save" option as a default so that I can avoid clicking the arrow every time and perhaps save myself some time as it helps if one is editing many photos at once.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same request, as im editing hundreds of photos... and have to click the down arrow to select save, event Ctrl+s goes straight to "save as" not "save".

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Your input is valuable and respected, but please put non-answers as comments on the question, not as answers. Look for "Add a comment" at the bottom of the answer.